# Is there any power plug that passengers may use on the Inca Rail train between Cusco and Machu Picchu in Peru?

Tags: trains, power, peru, machu-picchu, cusco

Is there any power plug that passengers may use on the  [Inca Rail](https://incarail.com/) train between [Cusco](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cusco) and  [Machu Picchu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machu_Picchu) in Peru?

Comment: When I was there in 2005, there definitely were no power outlets in the passenger cabin. Things could have changed, but I doubt it.

Comment: 2010 - none. But it's spectacular scenery. Enjoy the view!